# Как активировать кнопки при смене ROOT у STAGE?

Tags: java, javafx

Делаю формы в FXML
Переключюсь между ними

```
private void showStage(String fxml_source){
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxml_source));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Search on:"+fxml_source);
                for (Node node : anchorPane.getChildren()) {
                    System.out.println("Id: " + node.getId());
                    if (node instanceof Button) {
                        ((Button)node).setDisable(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

есть экраны где у меня заранее выключены кнопки и я не могу понять как мне их активировать через некоторое время.

Пытаюсь сделать через RunLater но он срабатывает на текущий загруженный FXML а не на тот который будет загружен

по логу вижу что runlater срабатывает на экран который уже будет скрыт

Answer (score 2):

Надо спрашивать потомков не у `anchorPane`, а у `root`, который был загружен с помощью `FXMLLoader'a`

```
private void showStage(String fxml_source) {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxml_source));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Search on:" + fxml_source);
            for (Node node: root.getChildren()) { // тут надо было искать у root, а не у anchorPane.
                System.out.println("Id: " + node.getId());
                if (node instanceof Button) {
                    ((Button) node).setDisable(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```